# How to check the user logged in - from direct login or using api access or using Oauth? If so can I block that user accessing certain objects?

Tags: security, transaction

How to check the user logged in - from direct login or using api access or using Oauth? If so can I block that user accessing certain objects?

Can I check the above using AuthSession object's sessiontype? or is there a way?

Once I find the user how he/she is logged in, how can I restrict the user to access only a few objects (for example Account, Contact and Opportunity only)

Answer (score 2):

You can't "block" access, but instead you would "grant" access. To do this, use a [Login Flow](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.securityImplGuide.meta/securityImplGuide/security_login_flow_examples.htm). You can determine their session type by way of the login flow variables presented to your flow, and, if they meet certain conditions, provide a [Session-Based Permission Set](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=perm_sets_session_use.htm&type=5) to access additional features. The base profile would only have limited access (e.g. Accounts, Contacts, and Opportunities), and additional access if the Login Flow grants access via the permission set.

Comment: Thank you @sfdcfox, I will look into these options.